CORS breaks in Vite dev server but works in Webpack dev server
Most of our development uses a mock backend server running on the same machine as the Vite/Webpack dev server.  We also need to connect the local dev server to the "real"  Java BE server deployed in AWS.  In this scenario, we use localhost.devcommweb100.somecompany.com as the localhost domain and the associated SSL cert/key for this domain that my company provides.  The remote Java BE hostname changes on each deployment but looks like this -- th-api-devmir2405212107.px.nonprod.somecompany.io.   When running our app locally under webpack dev server, it can make fetch requests to the remote host name just fine but when running the app locally under Vite dev server, the CORS policy breaks with the following error in the JS console.  It recommends altering the headers on the fetch request but that seems like the wrong approach and that tweaking the Vite server config is in order.  Does anyone know whats happening here?  Why does this work with Webpack dev server but not Vite dev server? --
https://th-api-devmir2405212107.px.nonprod.somecompany.io/px/th/appointment' from origin 'https://localhost.devcommweb100.somecompany.com:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
I'm not sure where to go from here and open to suggestions.
